# Iterate over the same data in different detail bands

Tags: java, netbeans, jasper-reports, ireport

I have SQL data as materials and material categories. I have to first show all materials with amounts, then in a lower area I have to show categories with sums of amount. Being a newbie, I assume I will need two detail bands. Can I iterate over the same data again for the second detail band to show categories (I have all the required data already fetched in the previous query)? What approach should I follow to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two subreports; each subreport can have its own query. Create two Detail Bands. Drop each subreport in its own Detail Band.

Also, consider using a Detail Band and Summary Band, instead of two Detail Bands.

Worry about optimizing later.